# Detecting changes to Django translations (PO) files in CI

Tags: django, testing, continuous-integration, translation, travis-ci

I am using [Django translations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/) for a project, and would like to ensure, on TravisCI, that translations are not left behind when changes are made to translatable strings.

This is a simplified snippet of my `.travis.yml`:

```
script:
 - ...
 - python manage.py makemessages -l ja --no-wrap --no-location
 - git diff --exit-code
```

That recreates the `PO` files, and fails when the file changes. So far so good.

Unfortunately, django updates the `POT-Creation-Date` every time the script is run, and I can't see any flags to `makemessages` that would disable that, so even if there are no changes, the file changes on every run.

Am I on the right lines, or is there a better way to detect that there has been a change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git now has a nice way to ignore specific matches. The following line will fail if there is a diff, but exclude the problematic header:

```
git diff --ignore-matching-lines=POT-Creation-Date --exit-code
```

What's better, Django recently merged a change to stop this header from getting updated when there are no changes to the translations. It hasn't been released as of Django 4.0, so I expect it will arrive in Django 4.1.

See [Django bug #6106](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6106) and [the commit that fixes this issue](https://github.com/django/django/commit/4bfe8c0eec835b8eaffcda7dc1e3b203751a790a).

Comment: Yes, this change is in Django 4.1+

Answer (score 3):

So, after makemessages diff will allways show at least 1 insert and 1 deletion, right?

```
git diff --numstat | awk '{if ($1>1 || $2>1) { exit 1 } else { exit 0 }}'
```

This script should exit with status=1 if there is more than 1 insert and 1 deletion in diff.

Comment: I found that calling `exit 0` caused only the first file to be checked when multiple `.po` files were changed. `git diff --numstat | awk '{if ($1!=1 || $2!=1) { exit 1 }}'` checks all of them, but is made redundant by my new answer.